# How to I transfer my old Windows files to my fresh install?

Tags: windows-7

Alright so I accidentally broke the thing where I choose which OS I want to run, so I re-installed Windows 7. I still have my old files (AKA windows.old)

I want to have everything that was in my old windows to sync in my new one, mostly because none of my drivers are installed, and I can't even connect to the internet because of it.

Okay I found a guide similar to what I want to do.  It involves renaming the folders.  Is there a method similar to this for Win7?

Answer (score 3):

The `Windows.old` directory contains all your previous data from the `Windows`, `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)` (*where applicable*), `ProgramData`, and `Program Files` folders. Each of these folders are required for a successful Windows Vista or above installation. I will offer 2 ways to get your data back, but both have drawbacks or advantages to each

## Put old install files back

**Advantages**: If it works, it's like nothing happened

**Disadvantages**: *If it works*

*For this method, you require another boot device or OS that can read/write NTFS partitions*

1. Boot off of a boot CD (such as Windows 7 Install DVD)
2. Get to a command prompt of some sort (For the Windows 7 Install DVD, click `Next` for the language, select `Repair your computer` in the bottom left corner, choose your Operating System and type an Administrator password, then choose Command Prompt from the bottom of the Repair screen)
3. Backup your older installation. Create a new folder (`Windows.Really.Old` for example), and `ROBOCOPY %folder% C:\Windows.Really.Old\%folder% /MOV /XJ /S /R:0 /W:0` the folders. The folders you need to move (replace %folder% in the above command with each of these) are:

   - Users
   - Program Files
   - Program Files (x86) (*if it exists*)
   - Windows
   - ProgramData

   Also remember to surround the path in `"` when the path name contains a space (i.e. `ROBOCOPY "C:\Program Files (x86)" "C:\Windows.Really.Old\Program Files (x86)" /MOV /XJ /S /R:0 /W:0`). This also assumes that the Windows drive is detected as `C:\`. To check for this, type `DIR C: /AD` and see if you see the above mentioned folders. If not, try with `D:` instead, and keep going up from there until you find the drive letter.
4. Once you have the folders moved, move the other folders back to the root directory. You can use the similar command as above, except using `C:\Windows.old` for the root folder.
5. Once this is done, I like to back up the *Boot Configuration Data* (BCD). Simply type `COPY C:\Boot\BCD C:\Boot\BCD.old` and press Enter.
6. Now, exit the command prompt (type `EXIT` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), then select Startup Repair. Let it run, as sometimes it needs to change the boot settings.
7. Once this is done, restart the computer, and cross your fingers. If it worked (not always), you will see your old Windows 7 installation. If this fails, you will need to re-install from scratch, and move on the method two.

## Start fresh, retrieve data

**Advantages**: Fresh copy of Windows, drivers and data are available

**Disadvantages**: Need to reinstall all extra programs, and put in all new settings

This method is my preferred way, as *usually* when I am installing a new copy of Windows, it gets rid of whatever cause the last one to mess up. In your case, because you didn't install Windows due to a malfunction, it may work for you to use the above method first.

1. Boot your new Windows installation
2. Make sure you have all the same user accounts as before (the ones you would click to log in with). Make sure you can log in as all these users
3. To copy the data back, I use drag and drop. The reason I don't use `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY` on the folders are because there are reminents of the old system that should not be copied to a new system.. Open both the `C:\Windows.old\Users\username` and the `C:\Users\username` folders, and stack them side to side (Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> on one window, and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> on the other).
4. Drag the following folders over from the OLD folder to the NEW:

   - Documents
   - Desktop
   - Contacts
   - Favourites
   - Music
   - Pictures
   - Videos
   - Downloads
   - Virtual Machines (if it exists)
   - Dropbox (if it exists)
5. Depending on email, you may be able to just move email messages and accounts over, or you'll need to import messages. That would be another topic. Lather, rinse, repeat for all the other user accounts.
6. To install drivers, click `Start`, right-click on `Computer` and click `Manage`. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd> if prompted. Select `Device Manager` from the list on the left. On the right side, look for any icons with a yellow triangle, black explanation mark (!) on it. Right-click each one, one at a time, and select `Update driver`. Select the option to choose a driver yourself from a folder, and point the <kbd>Browse</kbd> folder to `C:\Windows.old\Windows\System32`. Ensure the checkbox for `Include subfolders` is checked. Click Next, and it should pull the drivers from the previous installation, assuming it's the same version.

Comment: But what exactly do I have to do to change my data?  Just copy it over?

Comment: @brennan Updated answer

Comment: I was skeptical, but your instructions under the "Put old install files back" worked pretty flawlessly.

Comment: @buster don't forget to upvote,